# How can I have multiple losses in a network in Caffe?

Tags: neural-network, deep-learning, caffe, gradient-descent

If I define multiple loss layers in a network, will there be multiple back propagation happening from those ends to the beginning of the network? I mean, do they even work that way?

Suppose I have something like this:

```
Layer1{
}
Layer2{
}
...
Layer_n{
}
Layer_cls1{
bottom:layer_n
top:cls1
}
Layer_cls_loss1{
type:some_loss
bottom:cls1
top:loss1
}
Layer_n1{
bottom:layer_n
..
}
Layer_n2{
}
...
layer_n3{
}
Layer_cls2{
bottom:layer_n3
top:cls2
}
Layer_cls_loss2{
type:some_loss
bottom:cls2
top:loss2
}
layer_n4{
bottom:layer_n3
..
}
...
layer_cls3End{
top:cls_end
bottom:...
}
loss{
bottom:cls_end
top:loss:
type: someloss
}
```

So basically suppose instead of having one classification/loss per each network, we have several in between as well.

And in case they work, how could I add all the losses together and make my final loss the summation of all previous losses?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Caffe does this for you.
Furthermore, for each loss layer you have [`loss_weight`](https://github.com/BVLC/caffe/blob/master/src/caffe/proto/caffe.proto#L322-L325) parameter that allows you to decide how influential this specific loss is with respect to all other losses in the net.
Overall, the loss minimized by caffe is the *weighted* sum of all loss layers in the model.

Comment: Thanks again Shai:) Helpful as always :) 
if we put this simple form aside, and I need to accumulate these losses with a non trivial formula, how could I do that? Do I have to code this or can it be achieved using the normal/prototxt way ?

Comment: @Hossein what do you mean by "non trivial formula"?

Comment: I guess I found out my answer! heres another one, about the losses. 
suppose our first loss is calculated at layer 5, the second one at layer 10 and the last one at layer 15. 
Is this what happens ? 
when the flow reaches layer 5, back prop starts and weights are updated from layer 5 to the first layer, meanwhile, the forward prop continues to the next layers, till reaches layer 10, the same thing happens here, a backprop is initiated, and this goes untill we reach the last loss and the final back prop from the very end of the network

Comment: you are describing a scenario quite similar to the one described in [GoogLeNet](https://github.com/BVLC/caffe/tree/master/models/bvlc_googlenet) where loss was "injected" in different layers. AFAIK, caffe does a *full* forward pass, then computes all losses, takes the derivative and then update the weight in a backward pass. Naturally, layers > 5 will not be affected by the gradient of the loss at layer 5 (chain rule).

Comment: So, thats the way caffe does it, then how do you think I can do what GoogleNet did ? we have GoogleNet architecture in caffe right? so basically we should have had been able to do what Googlers did in their paper now that we have their models in caffe?!

Comment: Ok, I saw your link, This is what we are doing here as well right? it had 3 `SoftmaxWithLoss` layers, inside the network! and I think its cosmetically the same as what I am trying to do here!