# How do I get the weighted sum of multiple losses & accuracy (caffe)

Tags: neural-network, deep-learning, caffe

I have trained a network on two different modals of the same image. I pass the data together in one layer but after that, it is pretty much two networks in parallel, they don't share a layer and the two tasks have different set of labels, therefore I have two different loss and accuracy layers.

1. I have read that caffe averages multiple losses and accuracy (following this question [How can I have multiple losses in a network in Caffe?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42344012/how-can-i-have-multiple-losses-in-a-network-in-caffe)), is it the case only when at least a layer is shared? I intended to create an ensemble, however now it seems like I simply have two different networks. I intended to average the losses & accuracy so that both network branches would contribute to one accuracy. On training I see two separate losses & accuracy. How do I get this average loss & accuracy while testing on a new image pair?
2. By forwarding the network, is it possible to get two predictions at all? If so, how?

Comment: What do you mean by  'averaging' accuracy of the tasks ? If the tasks are different, what does the average of the corresponding accuracy give.

Comment: You have a good point. I have realized after posting this, what I have is merely two separate networks. What I wish is to jointly learn these two tasks. For example, the prediction of a class of task 1 should be higher in presence of the task 2 predicting a certain class label. I don't want to join them at feature level but at prediction level.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Multiple Losses can be used with one network using the caffe-parameter *loss_weight*. For example, you can have the following for one of your loss layers with weight 0.5 .

```
...
layer{
  name: "loss_a"
  type: "SigmoidCrossEntropyLoss"
  bottom: "fc8_a"
  bottom: "attributes_a"
  top : "loss_a"
  loss_weight : 0.5
 }

 layer{
  name: "loss_b"
  type: "SigmoidCrossEntropyLoss"
  bottom: "fc8_b"
  bottom: "attributes_b"
  top : "loss_b"
}
```